# Send SMS over IP

Tags: sms, sms-gateway

I hope to create a web server that can give some extra facilities for SMS Service Providers. Can I send SMS through internet? If its possible then, Are there any libraries for Send and Receive SMS over the internet?

Comment: You can send SMS through internet by using SMS Service Providers (Carrier or a third party provider). Provider gives you the API documentation and client side library (if library needed).

Comment: Actually I don't send it. When I developed it, it is used by the SP in their server. Let say It is an app to manage their SMS. And It can be used by any of SP in there servers. These SMS and SMS Protocols are completely new to me. But I'm going to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many different options to send SMS over Internet, but most popular are the following:

1. Connecting to SMSC of mobile carriers directly (usually via SMPP protocol).
2. Connecting through some SMS aggregation service like Clickatell mentioned in previous answers.

Choice between these options depends mostly on non-technical issues:

1. Required coverage (mobile carrier will provide only messaging inside it's network).
2. Premium Rate billing possibility (this requires closer work with carrier).
3. Well, price too... :-)

Technically most popular options are:

1. Specialized protocols like SMPP (Short Message Peer to Peer).
2. HTTP based protocols provided by SMS aggregators.

If you need unified solution, I recommend to use [Kannel](http://www.kannel.org/) open source SMS gateway that support many popular transports (SMPP, CIMD, UCP, HTTP, etc).

Comment: That's great. I need a unified solution. No 3rd parties. It should be able to work with many kind of SMS Protocols. I found [Ozeki NG](http://www.ozekisms.com) and now Kannel. If you know something about this please tell me.

Comment: Marvelous!  I am grateful to you about that tip (Kannel) you have given.

Answer (score 3):

You've got [www.Nexmo.com](http://www.Nexmo.com) [www.tropo.com](http://www.tropo.com) [www.twilio.com](http://www.twilio.com) [www.smsified.com](http://www.smsified.com) ... and so on...

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually I wanted another thing. Finally I found it from these answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use http://www.clickatell.com/ which gives you a few options such as sending SMS one by one, or by using bulk files such as XML.

I found the clickatell API to be really usefull and easy, I managed to add SMS capability to an existing website in a few hours by creating a simple class to wrap up all the methods.

One thing to remember though this is not going to be free for you, there will be costs involved depending on where you send the text to, and where you are based.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually I need to develop a thing which is exactly similar to clickatel at the begin of mine. I have some additional features (depends on the SP) to add. So how can I develop like this one?

Answer (score 1):

You can send SMS programmatically through [TheTexting API](https://www.thetexting.com), They provide cheap rates and their service is really good.

Full disclosure: I work for company that makes this product.